# React change state when time out using timestamp from the database

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, states

there is an element in my database that has a timestamp that represents the last time a component has been used. 
So, what I'd like to add is a functionality that when 20 minutes have past from the last time a component has been used React re-renders and change the color of the component. how do I give reactivity and make the website re-render when this event happens?

Comment: Would you like to dynamically re-render the component? Or is it fine to just check the the time when a component has been used on reload/remount of a component?

Comment: I want to dynamically re-render the component. So, the component re-render when the time past reach 20min after the value of the time stamp.

Comment: This seems like a problem you could fix with Socket.io. I haven't used it myself so I can't really give you any recommendation on that, but you could check out this article: https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34